# Regular Expression: Replace multiple input fields with their values

Tags: php, regex, forms, input, html-parsing

I want to use regular expressions to replace input tags with their corresponding values. 
The search must include the name of the input, since I have multiple inputs in the same form that need replacing.

For example, I need the following string:

```
<input value="Your Name" name="custom_field_1">
```

to become:

```
Your Name
```

My current code looks like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
   if($key == 'post_id') continue;
   $content = preg_replace("/<\s* input [^>]+ >/xi", htmlspecialchars($value), $content);
}
```

However, this will replace ALL inputs with the first value, so I need to refine the regex to include the name.

Thank you very much for your help!

- Ciprian

Comment: Why $_POST contains html `<input value="Your Name" name="custom_field__29541">` ? Maybe, you show `var_dum($_POST)` ?

Comment: var_dump for $_POST:

`array(7) { ["post_id"]=> string(4) "4495" ["custom_field_1"]=> string(7) "Value 1" ["custom_field_2"]=> string(7) "Value 2" ["custom_field_3"]=> string(7) "Value 3" ["custom_field_4"]=> string(7) "Value 4" ["custom_field_5"]=> string(7) "Value 5" ["custom_field_6"]=> string(7) "Value 6" }`

Comment: `echo $_POST["post_id"]; // 4495` You don't need any replacing

Comment: `echo $_POST["custom_field_1"]; // Value 1`

Comment: I found a regex that works: 

`$content = preg_replace("#<input([^>]*)name=['\"]".preg_quote($key)."['\"]([^>]*)>#Uis", htmlspecialchars($value), $content);`

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can match the whole string, capture the value by using parenthesis `(..)`, making a capture group, and replacing the match with `$1` - the first capture group.

`<input value="(.+?)" name=".*?">`

https://regex101.com/r/rH1wA2/3

Try:
`preg_replace("<input value=\\"(.+?)\\" name=\\".*?\\">", $1, $str)`

Note that this regex has "value", "name" and even spaces. If your strings sometimes look different, you have to take that to account and change the regex accordingly. `<input value="(.+?)"[^>]*>`, for example, to replace no matter what follows your desired value.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.
Just replace the match with `$1`

```
 # (?s)<input(?=\s)(?>(?:(?<=\s)value\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"|".*?"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+>)(?(1)|(?!))

 (?s)
 <input                        # Input tag
 (?= \s )
 (?>                           # Atomic grouping
      (?:
           (?<= \s )
           value  \s* = \s*              # 'value' attribute
           "
           (                             # (1 start), 'value' data
                [^"]+ 
           )                             # (1 end)
           "
        |  " .*? "
        |  ' .*? '
        |  [^>]*? 
      )+
      >
 )
 (?(1)                         # Conditional - Only input tags with a 'value' attr
   |  (?!)
 )
```

Sample:

```
<input type="hidden" value="Special:Search" name="title" />
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 59 ) 
<input type="hidden" value="Special:Search" name="title" />  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 28 , len 14 ) 
Special:Search
```